# Best way convert byte array to hex string

Tags: c#, array

Is it possible to write this method in a prettier way?

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray)
{
  var hex = new StringBuilder(byteArray.Length * 2);
  foreach (var b in byteArray)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are popular topics on StackOverflow that cover this exact question:

- [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)
- [byte[] to hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/c-sharp-byte-to-hex-string)

Comment: It seems that just as on StackOverflow, [consensus here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9036/7251) is that link-only answers aren't preferable.

Comment: This answer refers to internal stackoverflow links, not external. Basically it says “this question has already been answered”. I don’t see any reason to copy/paste the code from similar answers.